# Excel 2016 - Will not filter newest entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a previous Excel 2013 Pivot Table with approximately 260 rows and 11 columns of data.

After my Department upgraded to Excel 2016, the Filter function stopped working.  My last line of data was row 241 before the upgrade.  Everything above row 241 will filter correctly.  Everything after row 242 remains, regardless of category that is filtered.

I have tried to uncheck and recheck the "Filter" option, but the problem persists.

I have tried to search for Text Filters with "equals" then a category.  Rows above 241 work correctly, but the newest entries that do not match stay the same.

There are no blanks in any row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dominic try this help you,

Click anywhere in the PivotTable report.
This displays the PivotTable Tools, adding an
Options and a Design tab.

On the Options tab, in the PivotTable group, click Options .
In the PivotTable Options dialog box, on the Data tab, select the Refresh data when opening the file check box.